# Is a protocol (eg. http or https) required for a URL to be valid?

Tags: url, w3c, w3c-validation

Recently I came across a lot of code from analytics plugins where they specify the URL as `//fonts.googleapis.com` or `//www.google.com`.

Basically it starts with two forward slashes and then the domain or subdomain. These links work fine in browsers. I have read the following documents, but I am still not sure if above can be called valid URLs (basically should these be reported as broken URLs or not).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL and 
https://url.spec.whatwg.org/

Is there a standard specification that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both valid [scheme-relative-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-relative-url-string)s, although they need to be in the context of a Base URL to be meaningful. When used within a web page, the web page will provide the Base URL context.

Although there are other, earlier standards for URLs, the whatwg document represents the most up-to-date, web compatible definition.